# Pymodm - Mongodb, How to create an index in a collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymodm

I'm trying to create server side flask session extension that expires after # time. I found below `Mongodb` shell command in the documentation.

```
db.log_events.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

But how can I do it using `pymodm`?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the model definition: http://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/index.html?highlight=indexes#defining-models. There is a meta attribute called "indexes", that one is responsible for creating indexes. Here is an example:

```
import pymodm
import pymongo


class SomeModel(pymodm.MongoModel):

    ...

    class Meta:
        indexes=[pymongo.IndexModel([('field_name', <direction>)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Form the docs:

> indexes: This is a list of IndexModel instances that describe the
>   indexes that should be created for this model. Indexes are created
>   when the class definition is evaluated.

IndexModel is explained in [this](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.IndexModel) page.
Then add the following Meta class to your MongoModel class:

```
class Meta:
  indexes = [
    IndexModel([('createdAt', pymongo.ASCENDING)], expireAfterSeconds=3600)
  ]
```